# Prove $dω = 0 \iff$ {·, ·} is a Poisson bracket knowing that $\{f, g\} := X_f (g)$ and $i_{X_f} \omega = df$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, poisson-geometry

Let $\omega \in \Omega^2(M)$  be a non-degenerate 2-form. For a function $f \in C^\infty(M)$, define the vector field $X_f ∈ \mathscr X(M)$ via the relation:
$$i_{X_f} \omega = df$$,
where the first member is the interior multiplication and define the following binary operation on $ C^\infty(M)$
$$\{f, g\} := X_f (g)$$.

Show that

$dω = 0  \iff$ {·, ·} is a Poisson bracket.

I am new to the concept of interior multiplication and not very comfortable manipulating differentials, so I have no idea how to go about solving this. Any help is appreciated

Comment: See Theorem 13 on page 42 of https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/terekcouto.1/texts/symp_geo.pdf.

Comment: @IvoTerek, while the theorem is using the df, I don't see it using the interior multiplication that I am given in the problem and I don't know how to relate to the other objects in the problem

Comment: $\iota_{X_f}\omega = {\rm d}f$ means that $\omega(X_f,\cdot) = {\rm d}f$.

Comment: You might follow this derivation : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket#The_Poisson_bracket_in_coordinate-free_language